# Proximity sensor reports values like "38,654,705,664"

Tags: android, proximity, proximitysensor

My app uses the proximity sensor to switch the screen on/off while on the app's main Activity. This works fine, however I've received a crash report from a HTC One S user:

> 08-23 11:25:04.754 E/AndroidRuntime(30499): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-23 11:25:04.754 E/AndroidRuntime(30499): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "38,654,705,664"
>   08-23 11:25:04.754 E/AndroidRuntime(30499): at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>   08-23 11:25:04.754 E/AndroidRuntime(30499): at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
>   08-23 11:25:04.754 E/AndroidRuntime(30499): at java.lang.Integer.decode(Integer.java:188)
>   08-23 11:25:04.754 E/AndroidRuntime(30499): at com.myapp.MyActivity.onSensorChanged(NotificationActivity.java:793)
>   08-23 11:25:04.754 E/AndroidRuntime(30499): at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SystemSensorManager.java:204)

The code I'm using is

```
private NumberFormat numForm = new DecimalFormat(); 

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float sensor = event.values[0];
    String cm = numForm.format(sensor);
    int dis = Integer.decode(cm);

    Log.i(TAG, "Proximity distance: " + dis);
}
```

Is this a sensor calibration problem on the user's end, or can I simply surround the Integer-parsing with a try/catch to avoid obviously wrong values like "38,654,705,664"?

Comment: why don't simply call `int dis = (int) sensor;`?

Comment: The value in the stacktrace (38,654,705,664) exceeds `int`'s largest possible value (2,147,483,647), so that wouldn't help. I could use `long`, but 38,654,705,664 is obviously not a "real" proximity value, so I don't know what's going on here.

Comment: In your code you convert float to string and then string to int. If float exceeds max int value, what do you expect to see in log?

Comment: You're right, the float --> String step doesn't make any sense. However even `int dis = (int) sensor;` would also raise an exception in this, case, right? I'm asking more about *why* the sensor-value arrives in the first case - is it a sensor miscalibration on the user's end, or just a temporary "fluke" value that I should try/catch (and the sensor should work fine, apart from such a "bad" value)?

Comment: Casting form `float` to `int` does never cause an exception. We just lose precision in such cases like yours. If you need a full value, you should rather work with `float` and do not try to cast it. Not about bad values from sensor api. They can always come. If you can recognize them, you can exclude them from your calculations. If it is a hard requirement, you could implement some statistical filters. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, awesome, thanks for letting me know! I'll use the (int)-casting approach, then. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting form `float` to `int` does never cause an exception. We just lose precision in such cases like yours. If you need a "full" value, you should rather work with `float` and do not try to cast it. Now about bad values from sensor API. They can always come. If you can recognize them, you can exclude them from your calculations. If it is a must-requirement, you could implement some statistical filters. Hope this helps.